# Apache FOP 2.2 simulate-style attribute for font element in fop.xconf

Tags: apache-fop

I am trying to use a single font (FreeSans.ttf) for normal, bold and italic, but the `simulate-style` feature doesn't seem to have any effect.

This is the relevant font configuration:

```
<font kerning="yes" embed-url="FreeSans.TTF" simulate-style="true">
    <font-triplet name="Free Sans" style="normal" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="Free Sans" style="italic" weight="normal"/>
    <font-triplet name="Free Sans" style="normal" weight="bold"/>
    <font-triplet name="Free Sans" style="italic" weight="bold"/>
</font>
```

XSLT Transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <fo:root xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" font-family="Free Sans">
            <fo:layout-master-set>
                <fo:simple-page-master master-name="A4" page-width="210mm" page-height="297mm" margin-top="1cm" margin-bottom="1cm" margin-left="1cm" margin-right="1cm">
                  <fo:region-body/>
                </fo:simple-page-master>
            </fo:layout-master-set>
            <fo:page-sequence master-reference="A4">
                <fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
                    <fo:block>This <fo:inline font-weight="bold">document</fo:inline> is created with empty user stylesheet./fo:block>
                </fo:flow>
            </fo:page-sequence>
        </fo:root>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

C# Code for publish:

```
public static void Publish(string xslFoFile, string xConfFile, string outputFile, FopMode fopMode, bool cgmOption, NLog.Logger logger)
        {
            java.io.File xslFoFileFile = new java.io.File(xslFoFile);
            java.io.File xConfFileFile = new java.io.File(HttpUtility.UrlDecode(xConfFile));

            FopFactory fopFactory = FopFactory.newInstance(xConfFileFile);

            FOUserAgent foUserAgent = fopFactory.newFOUserAgent();

            EventListener eventListener = new FopEventListener(logger);
            foUserAgent.getEventBroadcaster().addEventListener(eventListener);

            if (cgmOption)
            {
                IIORegistry.getDefaultInstance().registerServiceProvider(new CGMImageReaderSpi());
            }

            OutputStream outputStream = new DotNetOutputMemoryStream();
            if (fopMode == FopMode.Fo2Pdf)
            {
                Fop fop = fopFactory.newFop("application/pdf", foUserAgent, outputStream);
                var transformerFactory = new org.apache.xalan.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl();
                var transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                StreamSource streamSource = new StreamSource(xslFoFileFile);
                var saxResult = new SAXResult(fop.getDefaultHandler());
                transformer.transform(streamSource, saxResult);
            }

            using (FileStream fileStream = System.IO.File.Create(outputFile))
            {
                var data = ((DotNetOutputMemoryStream)outputStream).Stream.ToArray();
                fileStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
        }
```

There is no any messages or errors while PDF rendering.

Comment: I made a quick test with a similar configuration and it seems to work as expected. (1) Are you actually using your configuration file (`fop -c fop.xconf input.fo output.pdf`)? (2) Do you get any warning / error message?

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question.

Comment: C#? I know there was a C# port of FOP, but it was _really_ old, so maybe that's the problem.